# How do you call the structure which only contains a single operator (such as below)?

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, structure

I have seen this question in a C++ test and I have no idea what the solution should be.
So in the code below, what is absValue?

```
#include <iostream> 

struct absValue  
{
       float operator()(float f) {
                 return f > 0 ? f : -f;
  }  
}; 

 int main( )   
{
   using namespace std;

  float f = -123.45;  absValue aObj;
  float abs_f = aObj(f);
  cout << "f = " << f << " abs_f = " << abs_f << endl;
  return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `absValue` is `struct absValue`. What do you know about structures or classes in C++?

Comment: What else could it be? It's an object, of course.

Comment: I would say that the correct answer is that absValue is a struct, but this question is for 3 points and I wouldn't give 3 points for an answer like this.

Comment: So it is a functor, thank you G.M., and bolov for answering it!

Comment: That is one of the many accurate ways to describe what it is. N.B. a functor need not have "only a single operator".